# How do you change the color of an Image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a .png image that's just white-on-transparent, and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to make that green-on-transparent, red-on-transparent, etc so I don't need to make separate .png files for each color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simpler solution that doesn't require pulling in huge libraries and lets you understand what's going on under their hood (and thus gives you greater flexibility), learn how to use WPF Pixel Shaders (google it).

Then you can use something like the multiply shader here: http://rakeshravuri.blogspot.com/2008/08/blending-modes-in-wpf-using.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at these CodeProject Articles

- [Image Processing Lab](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx)
- [ImageMagic-WPF Image Color Spaces](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ImageMagicImageColorSpace.aspx?display=Print)

> Image Processing Lab is a simple tool for image processing, which
>   includes different filters and tools to analyze images available in
>   the AForge.NET framework.

You could also take a look at the [FormatConvertedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx), [ColorConvertedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.colorconvertedbitmap.aspx) or [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) Class's