# Is it possible to change an ImageBrush color inside WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I'm trying to do something quite simple, but I'm not sure if it's possible. I have this image:

[image: Tile target]

Inside my board game project, I use this to indicate the mouse position in the board and stuff like that (being the board a 8x8 grid with a rectangle inside). I'm also setting the grid cell background brush as, say, a SolidColorBrush with Blue color and .25 opacity, while the rectangle that lies above it with the target, or vice-versa, because I couldn't achieve my desired effect, which is, the part that is black to turn full blue, as my brush, while the rest remains with the opacity and etc. The way I did, it was possible to make the black part become blueish, with a transluscent background, but the color in the border isn't quite right yet:

[image]

I don't know if I was able to make myself clear, but I guess the picture shows what is my goal.

The code:

```
            ImageBrush targetBrush = new ImageBrush();
            targetBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/GameScreen/selectedTile.png", UriKind.Relative));
            targetBrush.Opacity = 1;

            SolidColorBrush backBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            backBrush.Opacity = .25;

            tile.Children.Add(new Rectangle());
            foreach (object target in tile.Children)
            {
                if (target.GetType() == typeof(Rectangle))
                {

                    ((Rectangle)target).Fill = backBrush;
                }
            }



            tile.Background = targetBrush;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774635/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-an-image/8774798#8774798) I answered about WPF, not sure if it will work for Silverlight though.

Comment: My idea is to use WPF, but since it is so similar to SL, I put that tag too. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkHall I was kinda hoping that there was a solution for it inside WPF framework ... using that library would cost more than creating 5 different 50x50 monochromatic png files ;/

Comment: I have some WPF Classes referenced at the end of the answer did you look at them?

Answer (score 2):

As the image is just a mask you could use a `Rectangle` with a blue `Fill` and an [`OpacityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacitymask.aspx) set to your image.

Comment: Could you eleborate on how to actually do this? I can only find XAML examples but I have to set the OpacityMask from code behind and creating it from an ImageBrush does nothing.

Comment: @Lorgarn: It should work exactly the same in code behind (unless you work with names, that requires manually interacting with namescopes). Maybe the scaling of the brush is incorrect? Were you able to produce a working result using XAML? (Also i doubt that you really *have* to do that in code behind.)

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to do it this way, because my image comes from a database and I do not know it at runtime. I guess my issue is related there. I openend A question regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303226/can-not-create-opacitymask-from-byte

Comment: @Lorgarn: The only thing you need to do in code is fetching the image data (and possibly convert it to `ImageSource`), everything else can still be created and bound in XAML.