# How can I using code in C# for color extraction?

Tags: c#, object, extract, crop

I need help to extract specified color (red for example) from an image then cropping objects which contain this color.

This part is so important in my graduate project which tracking laser gesture in projector screen.

Comment: When you say cropping, you mean...? Would you like to remove red frame? Would you like to make all the red in the image white/transparent/etc?

Comment: i mean clipping the object with the  specified color

Comment: for example red ball in an imag

Comment: Take a look at the answer that I gave on a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/8774798/479512

Comment: Again, when you say clipping, what do you mean?

Comment: i mean that i need just a part from the image ( specified object)

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure I understood you correctly, but here is a code that makes only red parts of an image visible.

You can change it to only red parts invisible by changing > to < when comparing to 200.
You can also play with the number 200 to see what threshold is good for your is-red check.

```
private static unsafe void OnlyRed(Bitmap bitmap, Color replacement)
{
    var redOffset = 0;
    var bpp = 32;
    var bytesRep = new List<byte> {replacement.R, replacement.G, replacement.B};

    switch (bitmap.PixelFormat)
    {
        case PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
            bpp = 24;
            break;
        case PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
            redOffset = 8;
            bytesRep.Insert(0, replacement.A);
            break;
        case PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
        case PixelFormat.Canonical:
            bytesRep.Add(replacement.A);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Pixel format unsupported.");
    }

    var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                               ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                               bitmap.PixelFormat);

    var start = (byte*)data.Scan0;
    var end = start + data.Height * data.Stride;

    for (var curr = start; curr < end; curr += bpp / 8)
    {
        if (curr[redOffset] > 200)
        {
            continue;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < bytesRep.Count; i++)
        {
            curr[i] = bytesRep[i];
        }
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Usage:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap("file location...");
OnlyRed(bitmap, Color.Transparent);
```

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly? Are you getting an exception? Is the result wrong? How?

Comment: i have the image http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=ey2r55xu331gbtl
i need code in C# that find out the black rectangular in the image then clip the area in side it

Comment: You asked to clip red area, not black areas... Would you like me to modify the code to clip black parts instead?

Comment: In any case, it will only remove the black area itself. It does not recognize the area as a square and crops within it. What you are asking for now is much more advanced image processing.

Comment: Will there always be a rectangle? Will it always be the same size? Same color? How would you like the program to handle the crooked rectangle in the image you provided? It's really not straight. What if the background color is the same color is the rectangle? What if there is more than one rectangle? You're asking for something huge and give nothing to work with.

Comment: What will you ever use this for, anyway? If the user marks where the crop should be, he can crop it already.

Comment: user can not change any thing >> just need the limited part which will be shown in another picture box

Comment: Where did that rectangle come from? Why would you want what you're asking for? Why are you only answering the easy questions, and in a non-sufficient way?