# how can i crop an object in c# with a specified color?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, crop

i need a code in c#  which can extract a specified color (for example red )then clip the object which contain that color? that is mean searching for red object then cilp it

Comment: Please be more specific and maybe give us an example. Either with images (preferably) or with a longer description.

Comment: I did not down vote this question, but i can assume that the reason your question was downvoted was because there is not much information provided.  Also, it appears you asked an almost identical answer 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10257831/250725 and did receive an answer.  If the answers was not good enough you might want to update that question or leave a comment to the answerer so they can improve it.  Opening 2nd identical questions is usually going to result in a closed question

Comment: i can not upload an image because  i have not enough reputation

Comment: i need cropping according the color

Comment: So you want to create a new image from a source image that contains only 1 specific color?

Comment: not exactly..new image  contains only  specific objects with specific color

Comment: Since you can't upload images, maybe consider adding a link to the image hosted on another site.  That might help clarify the question and get you better answers.

Comment: for example ...
an image of tree i want to clip the green part only

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest to help you get good answers is to include what you tried and/or make an attempt yourself and where you are stuck.  Did you google "image object detection" as that seems to be the stumbling block here, not the color recognition since your earlier question covered that aspect.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is not as simple as I think you think it is.  Object detection in images is difficult as you need to algorithms to determine edges, in addition to your need to detect color.

I would look towards a 3rd party library rather than rewriting it yourself. Or you can use the library to detect the objects in your image, then look for the color you want.

I've never had a need to do this level of image processing in .Net, but here's a couple of examples I found in some quick google and SO searching.  Take a look an see if any suit your needs.

[AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/)

[Filters](http://filters.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i have the image http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=ey2r55xu331gbtl
i need code in C# that find out the black rectangular in the image then clip the area in side it

Comment: @Amani your followup question would get more attention if you edited your original question, or post as a new question.  However, people generally do not like to write code for you, so you should probably make an attempt yourself using the info i provided or doing some goolging, then post specific questions about what you are having trouble with.