# Transparent background and mouseEnter of a button - WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, styles

I have to create a button with an image and when I pass the cursor on it, the account icon has to change color, but I don't know how to do it, because for now when I pass on the button it changes the entire background.

Image without cursor
[image: Image without cursor]

Image with cursor
[image: Image with cursor]

There's my button's code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="TestAccountButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource Hoverless }" >
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!--MouseEnter-->
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="#3a3a3a" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <!--MouseLeave-->
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="White" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hoverless button:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="Hoverless">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is the image a Path? Can you post the code where you use the button...

Comment: @Marco The Image is in a folder, and the button has as code only the image source

Comment: ok. Then you should check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/bitmap-effects-overview#wpf-bitmap-effects

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774635/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-an-image-in-wpf

Comment: I've resolved in another way, thank you so much!

Comment: if you have the time, share the solution with us ;-)

Comment: Yeah, of course!!